# minimizing the cost of travel between cities

Tags: algorithm, optimization, shortest-path

Hi I have an optimization problem where I have n days to travel to k cities and I have to plan my travel such that my total cost of travel is minimized.

The cost of travel between any 2 cities u and v, is dependent on the day when i decide to travel( so cost  of travel between u and v is a function f(u,v,n) with n being the day when I am travelling)  and I can travel only once a day. 
I can also choose to stay in the same city.

Is there a way to solve this through a shortest path algorithm?

Comment: `Is there a way to solve this through a shortest path algorithm?` yes

Comment: This sounds like the travelling salesman problem, which is notorious for being hard to compute.

Comment: If the number of cities is not too large (k<12), then you can brute-force it by trying all possible routes (k!).

Comment: Shortest path algorithms are generally useful for finding the shortest path between exactly 2 points. It is generally not useful for this modified TSP. Also shortest path is only relevant if cost is proportional to the path length.

Answer (score 0):

This is an NP-Complete problem (since it reduces from the Hamiltonian Path). The only major difference between this and the standard Traveling Salesman Problem is that the edge weights are *dynamic*. This means that you face a one time preprocessing cost of O(V*V*E!) complexity and that the entire cycle can be solved in a O(V^3) worst case time.

I was able to find some details of a similar problem in this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5625106) published in IEEE, which describes the Intelligent Transportation-TSP problem.